# Java notification framework using Java RMI

Tags: java, networking, rmi

i must build a java application that implements a distributed notification framework using java rmi. I could not find anything on the web to get me started. any help?

Comment: Sounds like what you want is JMS.  This is designed for distributed messaging.

Comment: what kind of notification framework? what functionalities do you want? more details please.

Answer (score 0):

For ease of use, use [KryoNet](http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/), and then just take the [example](http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/source/browse/#svn/trunk/kryonet/examples/com/esotericsoftware/kryonet/examples/chatrmi/) and use that.

Comment: basically i was asked to implement the following:

A NotificationSource is an object that will notify registered NotificationSink objects when a
particular event happens. The idea is that NotificationSource objects are used on remote
machines to monitor the behaviour of certain components of a distributed system and to send
Notifications whenever particular events happen.

A NotificationSink object is registered with a NotificationSource and receives Notifications
every time the monitored event happens.

A Notification object is used to hold information about an event when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments on another question, it sounds like what you *really* want is JMX (which, like rmi, is already baked into the jdk).  it supports remote interaction (usually using RMI), includes a notification framework and is specifically designed for "monitoring the behaviour of components of a distributed system".  Details [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jmx/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to try googling either "RMI Callback" or "RMI Listeners". You should be able to find good examples of server-to-client applications.

This isn't saying that the JMS approach won't work, but I believe you want to go down the whole adding listeners to objects (similar to the way Swing and AWT deal with events)